# Dropdownlists loses SelectedIndexChanged when parent Gridview goes through programmatic databind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, event-handling

Tried researching this, but not really had any success in finding a similiar problem.

I have a gridview which contains a list of users and a dropdown of available permissions, allowing a user to change permissions of other users (subject to a set of inbuilt business logic). I've recently added the ability to "filter" users, to help make it more manageable, but now the SelectedIndexChanged events do not work, the pages postsback as expected, but it does nothing. Code below

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upUsers" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Table ID="tFilters" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <asp:TableRow VerticalAlign="Top">
                <asp:TableCell CssClass="sidepadding10"><b>Filters: </b></asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell CssClass="sidepadding10">
                    Permission Level<br />
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFilterPermission" runat="server"
                            DataSourceID="sdsPermission" 
                            DataTextField="PermissionName" 
                            DataValueField="PermissionLevelID"
                            AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Filter By Permission" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell CssClass="sidepadding10">
                    Unit<br />
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFilterUnits" runat="server"
                            DataSourceID="sdsUnit" 
                            DataTextField="UnitName" 
                            DataValueField="UnitID"
                            AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Filter By Unit" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvUsers" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsUsers" AutoGenerateColumns="false" PageSize="50" HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="User" DataField="FkUser" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hidden" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Permission Level" DataField="FkLevel" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hidden" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        User (PUID)
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle CssClass="sidepadding10" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lUser" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FkUser")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        Permission Level
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle CssClass="sidepadding10" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPermission" runat="server"
                            DataSourceID="sdsPermission" DataTextField="PermissionName" DataValueField="PermissionLevelID" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("FkLevel")%>'
                            AutoPostBack="true"
                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPermission_SelectedIndexChanged"
                            OnDataBound="ddlPermission_DataBound">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:Label ID="lPermission" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        Sub Permission
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle CssClass="sidepadding10" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubPermission" runat="server"
                            AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSubPermission_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Select Sub-Permission Group" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <PagerStyle CssClass="footer" />
            <PagerTemplate>
                <asp:GridViewPager ID="GridViewPager1" runat="server" />
            </PagerTemplate>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsUsers" runat="server"
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT FkUser, FkLevel, FkUnit, FkRegion, FkSection FROM CMT.dbo.UserPermissions UP INNER JOIN Common.dbo.Users U ON UP.FkUser = U.UserID ORDER BY FkLevel Desc, Surname, Forename"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsPermission" runat="server"
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT PermissionLevelID, PermissionName FROM PermissionLevels">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:SessionParameter SessionField="CMT#PermissionLevel" Name="Permission" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsUnit" runat="server"
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [UnitID], [UnitName] FROM Units U INNER JOIN UserPermissions UP ON U.UnitID = UP.FkUnit ORDER BY UnitName">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code Behind

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim Unit As String = ddlFilterUnits.SelectedValue
    Dim Permission As String = ddlFilterPermission.SelectedValue

    sdsPermission.SelectParameters.Clear()
    If ddlFilterUnits.SelectedValue = 0 And ddlFilterPermission.SelectedValue = 0 Then
        sdsUsers.SelectCommand = "SELECT FkUser, FkLevel, FkUnit, FkRegion, FkSection FROM CMT.dbo.UserPermissions UP INNER JOIN Common.dbo.Users U ON UP.FkUser = U.UserID ORDER BY FkLevel Desc, Surname, Forename"
    ElseIf ddlFilterPermission.SelectedValue = 0 And ddlFilterUnits.SelectedValue > 0 Then
        sdsUsers.SelectParameters.Add("Unit", ddlFilterUnits.SelectedValue)
        sdsUsers.SelectCommand = "SELECT FkUser, FkLevel, FkUnit, FkRegion, FkSection FROM CMT.dbo.UserPermissions UP INNER JOIN Common.dbo.Users U ON UP.FkUser = U.UserID WHERE FkUnit = @Unit ORDER BY FkLevel Desc, Surname, Forename"
    ElseIf ddlFilterPermission.SelectedValue > 0 And ddlFilterUnits.SelectedValue = 0 Then
        sdsUsers.SelectParameters.Add("Permission", ddlFilterPermission.SelectedValue)
        sdsUsers.SelectCommand = "SELECT FkUser, FkLevel, FkUnit, FkRegion, FkSection FROM CMT.dbo.UserPermissions UP INNER JOIN Common.dbo.Users U ON UP.FkUser = U.UserID WHERE FkLevel = @Permission ORDER BY FkLevel Desc, Surname, Forename"
    ElseIf ddlFilterPermission.SelectedValue > 0 And ddlFilterUnits.SelectedValue > 0 Then
        sdsUsers.SelectParameters.Add("Unit", ddlFilterUnits.SelectedValue)
        sdsUsers.SelectParameters.Add("Permission", ddlFilterPermission.SelectedValue)
        sdsUsers.SelectCommand = "SELECT FkUser, FkLevel, FkUnit, FkRegion, FkSection FROM CMT.dbo.UserPermissions UP INNER JOIN Common.dbo.Users U ON UP.FkUser = U.UserID WHERE FkUnit = @Unit AND FkLevel = @Permission ORDER BY FkLevel Desc, Surname, Forename"
    End If
    sdsUsers.DataBind()
    gvUsers.DataBind()

End Sub

Private Sub gvUsers_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvUsers.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        sqlParams.Clear()
        sql = "SELECT Forename, Surname, PUID FROM Users WHERE UserID = @UID"
        SQLDB.addParameterToList(sqlParams, "@UID", e.Row.DataItem(0).ToString)
        dt = SQLDB.fetchMultipleValues(sql, guestDB, sqlParams)
        Dim user As String = dt.Rows(0).Item("surname").ToString.ToUpper & ", " & dt.Rows(0).Item("Forename") & " (" & dt.Rows(0).Item("PUID") & ")"
        Dim l As Label = DirectCast(e.Row.Cells(2).FindControl("lUser"), Label)
        l.Text = user

        Dim ddlPermission As DropDownList = DirectCast(e.Row.Cells(3).FindControl("ddlPermission"), DropDownList)
        AddHandler ddlPermission.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ddlPermission_SelectedIndexChanged

        Dim ddlSubPermission As DropDownList = DirectCast(e.Row.Cells(4).FindControl("ddlSubPermission"), DropDownList)
        Dim subPermission As String = ""
        Select Case e.Row.Cells(1).Text.ToString
            Case "2"
                subPermission = e.Row.DataItem(2).ToString
                sql = "SELECT UnitID as ID, UnitName as Name FROM Units ORDER BY UnitName"
            Case "3"
                subPermission = e.Row.DataItem(3).ToString
                sql = "SELECT RegionID as ID, RegionName as Name FROM Regions ORDER BY RegionName"
            Case "4"
                subPermission = e.Row.DataItem(4).ToString
                sql = "SELECT SectionID as ID, SectionTitle as Name FROM Sections ORDER BY SectionTitle"
        End Select

        ddlSubPermission.Items.Clear()

        Select Case e.Row.Cells(1).Text.ToString
            Case "2", "3", "4"
                dt = SQLDB.fetchMultipleValues(sql, userDB)
                ddlSubPermission.DataSource = dt
                ddlSubPermission.DataValueField = "ID"
                ddlSubPermission.DataTextField = "Name"
                ddlSubPermission.DataBind()
                ddlSubPermission.Visible = True
                ddlSubPermission.SelectedValue = subPermission
            Case Else
                ddlSubPermission.Visible = False
        End Select
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub ddlPermission_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim ddl As DropDownList = DirectCast(sender, DropDownList)
    Dim gvr As GridViewRow = DirectCast(ddl.Parent.Parent, GridViewRow)
    Dim l As Label = DirectCast(gvr.Cells(2).FindControl("lUser"), Label)

    sqlParams.Clear()
    SQLDB.addParameterToList(sqlParams, "@User", gvr.Cells(0).Text)
    SQLDB.addParameterToList(sqlParams, "@newLevel", ddl.SelectedValue)
    sql = "UPDATE UserPermissions SET FkLevel = @newLevel WHERE FkUser = @User"
    SQLDB.executeSqlCUD(sql, userDB, sqlParams)
    Response.Redirect("~/UserManager.aspx")

End Sub
```

Please be aware this is not all the code, I've only included part of the code. I am pretty sure its to do with the page lifecycle, but I can't figure out why it's acting as it is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are over databinding, and you're implementing filters incorrectly.

**Regarding Databinding:** If the postback occurs as a result of changing the filter DDL, you call sdsUsers.DataBind AND gvUsers.DataBind which is overkill.  Since control events occur before databind events, this is bind #1 and #2

Since you are supplying a Gridview DataSourceID, your Gridview will auto databind each postback.  That's bind #5.

Note I say that's #5, you also provide a DataSourceID for your two "filter" ddls, so they databind too, and since they appear before the gridview in the control hierarchy they databind first, that's bind #3 and #4.  BUT - there is a thing about DDL's:

***From  [MSDN Library: ListControl.SelectedIndex Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx)***

> The value of the SelectedIndex property is not specifically saved on
>   postback. It is restored on postback using the SelectedValue property.
>   For example, if the SelectedValue property is 4, on postback, the
>   SelectedIndex property is set to the index of the ListItem object that
>   has a Value property of 4. If more than one ListItem object has a
>   Value property of 4, the first item in the Items collection is
>   selected.

In your code I'd check to see if you are performing a clear anywhere on the ddl's, that will effectively clear any prior selected values.

**Regarding filtering:** It's built into the SqlDataSource control.  You don't do it by specifying a new select command, but by providing filter conditions to the whole dataset.  Look up [SqlDataSource Filter Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59bfya48(v=vs.100).aspx).

---

**Addendum: 1/14/2015 12:20pm**

Apologies for misunderstanding which DDL you were referencing.

FYI: a DDL ***is*** a ListControl.  Take a look at the inheritance hierarchy.

Regarding the lost events, your Page_Load event is forcing a rebind (twice) **regardless of whether you select a filter**.

All bets are off at this point because the embedded DDLs in the Gridview are also going to be rebound which means any events that the embeded DDL's would have fired are now lost.

Also, a word about [**Databinding**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx#data_binding_events_for_databound_controls):  Do not confuse "data binding" with "hitting the database." During the Page life cycle `PreRender` event, every Databound control that has its **DataSourceID** set is going to get it's Databound event raised, let alone when you call Databind() explicitly.  Cacheing just limits how often a full round trip to the database is needed based on the rules you set for the cache.

Comment: Thanks for the "answer" but 1) my filtering worked, unlike the link you gave me to the Filter Parameters, which did nothing (or rather it posts back, but doesn't change the gridview at all). 2)The filter dropdowns were not the issue, its the dropdowns WITHIN the gridview that lose thier events and I know they lose their events as I have run it through debug and the events do not fire when expected to. 3) Dropdown and List Controls are different, as a dropdown can only have 1 SelectedValue property, so the copy from MSDN is irrelevant.

Comment: Just to add, yes I enabled caching and changed the DataSourceMode to Dataset

Comment: Well, its now at the point that if I don't have the databinds the ddls withing the gv work, but the filtering doesn't work. If I put one of the databinds (the gv), the filters work, but the ddls within the gv don't. I've tried re-attaching the events to the ddls at different points (page load, gv databound, pre-render to name some) but no joy.

Comment: The only thing that should be happening when you select a "filter" value from the DDL's is that the chosen value should be stored in some round trip safe storage location that is accessible by the gridview such that the selected values are part of the `select` criteria of the gridview, for instance as SessionParameters or ControlParameters, or even FilterParameters, This is how filtering is done. Selecting a DDL value should not rewrite the SQL statement for the gridview.

Comment: Sure - see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.filterexpression(v=vs.110).aspx) and [this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Filter-GridView-with-DropDownList-using-FilterExpression-in-SqlDataSource-in-ASPNet.aspx) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/714411/ASP-NET-Gridview-with-Filter-in-Header)